# Copy and paste VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project which needs a lot of copy and paste cells between work sheets in excel which are not in order .I could barely program VBA . I am thinking that if i can write a program (click or right click to copy to clip board  and double click to paste in different work sheet) that could make my work faster .Please suggest me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an excel formula to copy from one sheet to another

follow the instructions on this site

http://ccm.net/faq/9795-transfer-data-between-excel-spreadsheets

it basically says to

in the target cell type +
then select the source worksheet
click on the source cell
then hit enter

these steps will make a copy of, for example, work sheet 1, cell A1 into work sheet 2 cell A1

the formula is as follows =+Sheet1!A1

I hope this is of some help to you

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, but let me first explain one thing to you.

When you are copying and pasting cells, you are actually using the Microsoft clipboard which is rather memory intensive process, and while this is the go to default option you could just as easily just assign value to value which doesn't use the clip board.

No frills option:

```
Sub Copy_and_Paste()
Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Range("Your Range").Copy
Sheets("Your Destination Sheet Name").Range("Your Destination Range").Paste
End sub
```

Example No frills

```
Sub Copy_and_Paste()
Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A10").Copy
Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("B1:B10").Paste
' You don't have to paste them in the exact same range.
' Just make sure they are the same size.
End sub
```

Values option

```
Sub Value_to_Value()
Sheets("Your Destination Sheet Name").Range("Your Destination Range").value = Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Range("Your Range").value
End sub
```

Example Values

```
Sub Value_to_Value
Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("B1:B10").value = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:A10").value
End sub
```

Experiment with both to come up with the version you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.This works but my problem is data is not even it is all over the place which i need to organize in another sheet.